# Let $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$. Understanding a proof that if $5\nmid xy$ then $5\nmid x$ and $5\nmid y$

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

I have to prove this by contradiction. The result of my textbook is "Assume that $5\mid x$ or $5\mid y$. Say the former. Then $x=5a$ for some integer $a$. Thus, $xy=(5a)y=5(ay)$. Since $ay$ is an integer, $5\mid xy$, contradicting the assumption that $5\nmid xy$.

I don't get it. Why did they say "Assume that $5\mid x$ or $5\mid y$" and not "Assume that $5\mid xy$"?

If I assume that $5\mid xy$ I can't find a way to prove it though. Why did they do it like that?

Comment: the contrapositive is not $(5\nmid x$ and $5\nmid y)\implies$  not $(5\nmid xy)$, which is equivalent to $5|x $ or $5|y\implies 5|xy$

Comment: To do a proof by contradiction, you assume the negation of the conclusion, so you assume $$\text{NOT ($5∤x$ and $5∤y$)}$$

Comment: Which textbook are you referring to?

Comment: Use `$5\nmid x$` for $5\nmid x$ and `$5\mid x$` for $5\mid x$.

Comment: @LeeMosher oh my god yeah ‍♂️ it's late over here and i had a busy day, i just started studying at 22.26pm.. i think i should go to sleep lol thanks by the way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many sources conflate proofs by contradiction with proving the contrapositive, so I will explain both here.

**Proving the contrapositive**: by definition, the contrapositive of the implication "If P, then Q" is the implication "If (not Q), then (not P)." It is a fundamental fact of logic that the contrapositive of an implication is logically equivalent to the original implication. Therefore, if we want to prove "If P, then Q", one way to do so is to prove the contrapositive "If (not Q), then (not P)" instead. That gives us extra flexibility in our approach.

Here, the original statement is "If $5\nmid xy$, then $5\nmid x$ and $5\nmid y$." Its contrapositive is therefore "If (not ($5\nmid x$ and $5\nmid y$)), then (not $5\nmid xy$)," which is equivalent to "If $5\mid x$ or $5\mid y$, then $5\mid xy$." (Remember that the negation of an and-statement is an or-statement.) This is pretty easy to prove, in the manner you indicated in the OP.

**Proof by contradiction**: here, if we can derive a contradiction by supposing that the original statement is false, that is enough to prove the original statement. In this case, proving "If $5\nmid xy$, then $5\nmid x$ and $5\nmid y$" by contradiction would begin with the assumption "Not (if $5\nmid xy$, then $5\nmid x$ and $5\nmid y$)", which is equivalent to "$5\nmid xy$ and (not ($5\nmid x$ and $5\nmid y$))" and therefore equivalent to "$5\nmid xy$ and ($5\mid x$ or $5\mid y$)", and then attempt to derive a contradiction from it. (Remember that (the negation of "if P then Q") is logically equivalent to "P and (not Q)".) This is essentially what the proof in the OP does, although itt only mentions one assumption ($5\mid x$ or $5\mid y$) at the beginning and doesn't mention the other assumption ($5\nmid xy$) until the end.

In my opinion, it is much better to learn to prove the contrapositive when possible, because proofs by contradiction are inherently tricky (we have to remember we're in a hypothetical situation that we're trying to prove impossible, and small mistakes often lead to invalid contradictions that are hard to troubleshoot). In this case, in particular, I think that proving the contrapositive "If $5\mid x$ or $5\mid y$, then $5\mid xy$" is much superior than phrasing it as a proof by contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Let $5∤xy$ and $k\in Z$ then $xy\not=5k$ that is

$xy$ is equal to one of the forms $\space$$5k+1$,$\space$
$5k+2$, $\space$$5k+3$,   $\space$ $5k+4$

Suppose that $5|x$ and $5|y$ then both $x$ and $y$ are in $5k$ form.

It is obvious that by multiplying two numbers of the form  $5k$ it is not possible to get a number in the other four forms(it will be $5k$ form and that is $xy|5$). It is contradict with the assumption.

Then if $5∤xy$ then $x\not=5k$ and $y\not=5k$

$5∤x$ and $5∤y$